# TypeError in await asyncio.sleep ('dict' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have recently started to use python and have received the following error log on my `aiohttp` server:

```
ERROR:app.handlers.socket_handler:'dict' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/app/handlers/socket_handler.py", line 47, in try_coroutine
    await coroutine
  File "[...]/app/handlers/socket_handler.py", line 65, in do_stuff
    async for data in stuff_repo.observe_stuff(search=param_search):
  File "[...]/app/repositories/stuff_repository.py", line 74, in observe_stuff
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

This does not make any sense to me, since at no point there are `dict` objects nor `callable`s involved in the `asyncio.sleep` call, and `sleep_for` is an int of value 30, witch at no point is modified, only read:

What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: You'd have to paste your code, but from the given message, I can only understnd at at soe point you did an assignment of a dictionary to asyncio.sleep, overriding the function. (A line such as `asyncio.sleep = {}`)

Comment: No, there are no assignments to asyncio.sleep in the whole project. I don't know if its relevant, but I am pretty sure this only happens when I am debugging (putting breakpoints) with PyCharm. Either that or I am just paranoid.

Comment: Did you perhaps name a module `asyncio.py` or have one lying around?

Comment: No, there is no module on the project with the same name, and it is imported directly like this: `import asyncio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a PyCharm bug, as it only caused when a breakpoint is added while already debugging.

Fix:
Add environment variable `PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO`

Sources:

[Debugging asyncio code in PyCharm causes absolutely crazy unrepeatable errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936199/debugging-asyncio-code-in-pycharm-causes-absolutely-crazy-unrepeatable-errors)

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25856